# Let $E$ be a separable Banach space. Then ${E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in the weak$^{\star}$ topology $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, separable-spaces, weak-topology

I'm reading section *3.6 Separable spaces* in Brezis's *Functional Analysis*.

---

Separability properties are closely related to the metrizability of the weak topologies. Let us recall that a topological space $X$ is said to be metrizable if there is a metric on $X$ that induces the topology of $X$.

- **Theorem 3.28.** Let $E$ be a separable Banach space. Then $\color{red}{B_{E^{\star}}}$ is metrizable in the weak$^{\star}$ topology $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$. Conversely, if $B_{E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$, then $E$ is separable.
- **Theorem 3.29.** Let $E$ be a Banach space such that ${E^{\star}}$ is separable. Then $\color{blue}{B_E}$ is metrizable in the weak topology $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$. Conversely, if $B_E$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$, then $E^{\star}$ is separable.

---

**My understanding:**

- A Banach space is separable [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498281/unit-ball-in-a-separable-banach-space) its closed unit ball is separable.
- It seems the proof of the first direction of **Theorem 3.28.** generalizes without problem to [.... $E$ be a separable Banach space. Then $\color{red}{{E^{\star}}}$ is metrizable ...].
- I don't know if the generalization [... ${{B_{E^{\star}}}}$ is separable. Then $\color{blue}{E}$ is metrizable ...] is true for **Theorem 3.29.**

To sum up, could you confirm if below statements are correct?

- **S1:** Let $E$ be a Banach space such that $B_E$ is separable. Then $\color{red}{E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in the weak$^{\star}$ topology $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$. Conversely, if $B_{E^{\star}}$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$, then $E$ is separable.
- **S2:** Let $E$ be a Banach space such that ${{B_{E^{\star}}}}$ is separable. Then $\color{blue}{E}$ is metrizable in the weak topology $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$. Conversely, if $B_E$ is metrizable in $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$, then $E^{\star}$ is separable.

Comment: Weak topologies in infinite dimensional spaces are never metrizable (or evan first countable).

Comment: As David said ... S1 and S2 are false for every infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DavidMitra mentioned in a comment, my claim is wrong. Indeed, the author of the book has a remark just right after the proof of Theorem 3.28, i.e.,

> **Remark 20.** One should emphasize again (see Remark 3) that in infinite-dimensional spaces the weak topology $\sigma\left(E, E^{\star}\right)$ (resp. weak ${ }^{\star}$ topology $\sigma\left(E^{\star}, E\right)$ ) on all of $E$ (resp. $E^{\star}$ ) is not metrizable; see Exercise 3.8. In particular, the topology induced by the norm [ ] on all of $E^{\star}$ does not coincide with the weak ${ }^{\star}$ topology.