# If $X$ is locally compact and $\mathcal C_c (X)$ is separable, then $X$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-topology

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions,
- $\mathcal C_0(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions that vanish at infinity, and
- $\mathcal C_c(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions with compact supports.

Then $\mathcal C_b(X)$ and $\mathcal C_0(X)$ are real Banach space with supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. It's mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184766/when-is-c-0x-separable?rq=1) that *"if $E$ is locally compact and separable, then $\mathcal C_0 (E)$ is separable"*. Now I would like to prove a somehow reverse direction, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is locally compact and $\mathcal C_c (X)$ is separable, then $X$ is separable.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof:** Because $\mathcal C_0(X)$ [is the closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566771/mathcal-c-0x-is-the-closure-of-mathcal-c-cx-in-mathcal-c-bx-is-l) of $\mathcal C_c(X)$ in $\mathcal C_b(X)$, it suffices to show that

> If $X$ is locally compact and $\mathcal C_0 (X)$ is separable, then $X$ is separable.

Let $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of finite signed Radon measures on $X$. Let $[\cdot]$ be the total variation norm on $\mathcal M(X)$. We define a map
$$
f:X \to \mathcal M(X), x \mapsto \delta_x.
$$

Notice that $f(X)$ is a subset of the closed unit ball of $\mathcal M (X)$. Let $E := \mathcal C_0 (X)$. By [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500358/3-versions-of-riesz-markov-kakutani-theorem), $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is isometrically isomorphic to $E^*$ though a canonical map $\Phi:\mathcal M(X) \to E^*$. Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $E^*$. Clearly, $\Phi \circ f (X) \subset B$.

By Banach-Alaoglu's theorem, $B$ is compact in the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(E^*, E)$. Because $E$ is separable, the subspace topology $\sigma_B(E^*, E)$ that $\sigma(E^*, E)$ induces on $B$ [is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546596/let-e-be-a-separable-banach-space-then-e-star-is-metrizable-in-the-wea?rq=1). It follows that $\sigma_B(E^*, E)$ is compact metrizable and thus separable.

If one proves that $\Phi \circ f$ is a [homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567328/the-bijection-in-riesz-markov-kakutani-theorem-is-a-homeomorphism-w-r-t-both-no) from $X$ (together with metric topology) onto $\Phi \circ f(X)$ (together with its subspace topology induced by $\sigma_B(E^*, E)$),  It would follow that $X$ is separable.

Comment: Why is $\Phi\circ f$ a homeomorphism between $X$ and $\Phi(f(X))$? It is clear a continuous bijection. But I think a few words need to be said about $(\Phi\circ f)^{-1}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz You're right! I'm thinking of how $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_x$ in weak$^*$ topology implies $x_n \to x$ in metric topology.

Comment: That requires a proof.

Comment: you may try to polish what I wrote in my posting regarding the continuity of $(\Phi\circ f)^{-1}$.

Comment: (+1) The question is a good one. I am aware of the similar result for weak convergence in probability: namely that $\delta_{x_n}\Longrightarrow\delta_x$ iff $x_n\rightarrow x$. In the same setting, it can be shown that $\{\delta_x:x\in X\}$ is closed in $\mathcal{M}^+(X)$ with the topology $\sigma(\mathcal{M}(X),\mathcal{C}_b(X))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\Phi\circ f: X\rightarrow\Phi(f(X))$ is a homeomorphism it seems that is enough to show that for any sequence $(x_m:m\in\mathbb{N})\subset X$, $\delta_{x_m}\stackrel{v}{\longrightarrow}\delta_x$ iff $x_m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty} x$ in $X$.

Sufficiency is obvious. As for necessity, I suggest the  OP to consider a sequence of open and relatively compact neighborhoods $V_n$ around $x$ such that
$V_{n+1}\subset\overline{V_{n+1}}\subset V_n$, and $\operatorname{diam}(V_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Then define functions  $f_n\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X)$ with $0\leq f_n\leq 1$ such that $f_{n+1}=1$ on $\overline{V_{n+1}}$ and $f_n=0$ on $X\setminus V_n$. Then
If $\delta_{x_m}\stackrel{v}{\rightarrow}\delta_x$, for any $n$,
$f_n(x_m)\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)=1$. This means that for all $m$ large enough, the $x_m$ are close to $x$, i.e. $x_m\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}x$.

Comment: Luckily, I have just posted a different approach as an answer. Could you please have a check on it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @OliverDíaz, the fact that $f^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism (in weak$^*$ topology of $\mathcal M(X)$) from $f(X)$ onto $X$ is not clear. I have added a proof below.

---

WLOG, we assume $d \le 1$. For $x \in X$ and $r>0$, let

- $B_r (x)$ be the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.
- $\overline B_r (x)$ the closed ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.
- $\overline{B_r (x)}$ the closure of $B_r (x)$.

Notice that $\overline{B_r (x)} \subset \overline B_r (x)$ but **not** necessarily that $\overline{B_r (x)} = \overline B_r (x)$. Assume $a, x_n \in X$ such that $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_a$ in weak$^*$ topology, i.e.,
$$
\forall f \in \mathcal C_0(X) : \int_X f \mathrm d \delta_{x_n} \to \int_X f \mathrm d \delta_{a} \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$

Because $X$ is locally compact, there is a sequence $(r_m) \subset \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $r_m \searrow 0$ and $\overline B_{r_m} (a)$ is compact.  Clearly, $\overline{B_{r_m} (a)}$ is compact. Let $C_m := X \setminus B_{r_m} (a)$, and
$$
f_m (x) := d(x, C_m) \quad \forall x \in X.
$$

Then $f_m \in \mathcal C_b(X)$. Because $C_m$ is closed,
$$
f_m (x) \neq 0 \iff d(x, C_m)>0 \iff x \notin C_m \iff x \in B_{r_m} (a).
$$

So
$$
\operatorname{supp} (f_m) = \overline{B_{r_m} (a)}.
$$

Hence $f_m \in \mathcal C_c (X)$ and thus
$$
f_m(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f_m(a) \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N.
$$

This implies
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, C_m) = d(a, C_m) \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N.
$$

As such,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, a) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, C_m) + d(a, C_m) = 2 d(a, C_m) \le 2r_m  \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N.
$$

The proof is completed by taking the limit $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Using $g(y)=\min(1,d(x,y))$ works if you were considering $C_b(X)$ instead of $C_0(X)$ as your space of test functions. $g$ is not in $C_0(X)$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I may be wrong, but I proved that $A_\varepsilon := \{x \in X : |g(x)| \ge \varepsilon \}$ is compact for all $\varepsilon >0$. This is the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566771/mathcal-c-0x-is-the-closure-of-mathcal-c-cx-in-mathcal-c-bx-is-l) of $\mathcal C_0(X)$.

Comment: Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$. $g(x)=\min(1,|x|)$ does not vanish at infinity.

Comment: @OliverDíaz You are right! I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: your proof is not correct.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have just fixed my proff. Could you please have a check on it again?

Comment: I had originally thought about some argument like that (using distant function to the neighborhoods $V_n$ in my solution but did not precede any further as the Uryshoh-lemma seem to yield a more direct proof) in any event, I think that does it. The trick is to show that the sequence $x_n$ gets trap in neighborhoods of $x$ as small as we want using a clever sequence $f_m\in \mathcal{C}_0(X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated discussion @OliverDíaz ! It's funny that I had tried applying Uryshoh lemma and Tietze extension theorem, but to no avail. Then the distance function came in :)

Comment: The use of the distance function in my argument is in the fact that $\operatorname{diam}(V_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ by choice. Using relatively compact balls around $x$ was a good way to fix your previous argument.